# SQL Server 2014 - Restarting Service from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Just installed a new SQL Server 2014 instance. When I try to restart the sql server instance in SSMS by right-clicking and choosing restart, I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Unable to restart service MSSQL$SQLSERVER on server SQLSERVER. (mscorlib)

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

The object invoked has disconnected from its clients. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010108 (RPC_E_DISCONNECTED)) (mscorlib)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of restart try stop and start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting error from SSMS, try to restart the service from `SQL Server configuration manager` or from `Services.msc`.

From `Services.msc`

```
Run>Services.msc>Right Click on required SQL Server service>Stop>Start
```